# WPF - Access the control that was shown up on MouseOver

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

This may be trivial.  Not sure, I'm surprised that I'm unable to find the solution.  May be I'm out of mind now as my weekend starts :P.

**Goal:**  In a `TreeView`, each item has a `CheckBox` and a `Content`.  Also, there will be a option to delete the `TreeViewItem` that will shows up only on `MouseOver` over the item.

**Problem** is when I hover the mouse on item, it trigger the `Visibility` of the `Button` to show up.  Now, when I try to move the mouse towards the `Button` to delete, it got `Hidden` as the `IsMouseHover` was `false` now.

Here is the sample:

```
 <TreeView Grid.Column="2" Name="trvMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20" MaxHeight="200" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestPlan}" ItemsSource="{Binding Plans}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Margin="5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="5"/>
                <Button Height="20" Width="20" x:Name="deletebutton" Margin="5" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Image Source="/Images/cross.png" Height="20"/>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="deletebutton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I need to access the `Button` on `MouseOver`

Is there any easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the `IsMouseOver` gets lost between the `TextBox` and the `Button` because of the `Margin` and because your `StackPanel` has no `Background`.

(If `Background` is `null`, it influences the HitTestResult)

```
<StackPanel Background="Transparent"  Orientation="Horizontal">
```

If that's not enough, remove the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers`, remove the explicitly set `Visibility` on the button and use something like this instead (Style setters cant't overwrite values set in XAML under certain conditions):

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```